# PostgreSQL - is it allowed/good practice to use bound values as arguments to PostgreSQL functions?

Tags: postgresql

Using, for example C++, Qt, QSqlQuery to access the database,

given an arbitrary PostgreSQL function, for example:

```
SPLIT_PART('blah,blah', ',', ?)
```

Would there be any issues with using a bound parameter as the last argument?

Comment: No, why do you think there was sometihng wrong with this? Parameters can be used in place of any expression.

Comment: The only potential problem is if you bind the parameter with a wrong data type.